# Tor can not connect when trying to use ExitNodes from Iran

Tags: configuration, exit-relays

I'm visiting a website that only is available from Iran, and I want to use Tor and I want Tor to use an exit node from Iran, So, I put this on the **torrc** file:

```
ExitNodes {ir}
StrictNodes 1
```

But, I get this error and Tor can't connect. Here is the Tor log:

```
Oct 29 09:24:51.090 [notice] Tor v0.2.6.8 (git-5c8440b13bde6c88) running on Linux with Libevent 1.4.13-stable, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips and Zlib 1.2.3.
Oct 29 09:24:51.090 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
Oct 29 09:24:51.090 [notice] Read configuration file "/etc/tor/torrc".
Oct 29 09:24:51.092 [notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050
Oct 29 09:24:51.000 [notice] Parsing GEOIP IPv4 file /usr/share/tor/geoip.
Oct 29 09:24:51.000 [notice] Parsing GEOIP IPv6 file /usr/share/tor/geoip6.
Oct 29 09:24:51.000 [warn] You are running Tor as root. You don't need to, and you probably shouldn't.
Oct 29 09:24:51.000 [notice] We were built to run on a 64-bit CPU, with OpenSSL 1.0.1 or later, but with a version of OpenSSL that apparently lacks accelerated support for the NIST P-224 and P-256 groups. Building openssl with such support (using the enable-ec_nistp_64_gcc_128 option when configuring it) would make ECDH much faster.
Oct 29 09:24:51.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 0%: Starting
Oct 29 09:24:51.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server
Oct 29 09:24:51.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 45%: Asking for relay descriptors
Oct 29 09:24:52.000 [notice] I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We need more microdescriptors: we have 6579/6579, and can only build 0% of likely paths. (We have 100% of guards bw, 100% of midpoint bw, and 0% of exit bw = 0% of path bw.)
```

Look at the last notice, It stops right there and nothing more.
By the way, Im using Tor command line, on CentOS 6.6.

I will appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only one relay in Iran, and it is flagged as a Bad Exit.

https://atlas.torproject.org/#details/CD1CD537A9BB9203BFD7327E53843DAA3B9E521D

See this question: [What specifically causes an Exit to get a Bad Exit flag?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/253/what-specifically-causes-an-exit-to-get-a-bad-exit-flag)  for how exits are flagged as "Bad".

Comment: Why is it a bad exit?

Comment: And, excuse me, how many IPs does an exit have?

Comment: Considering that there is one exit, Why Tor cant connect to it

Comment: I edited my answer to add a link to a question about Bad Exits.

Comment: Thanks, are you saying that there is absolutely no way to use Tor and have an IP address from Iran?

Comment: Not as long as there is no *good* exit there.